# Changing the \printglosssary output with leipzig package

Tags: linguistics, leipzig

Consider the following MWE -

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{leipzig}
\makeglossaries
\renewcommand{\firstleipzigfont}[1]{\textit{\leipzigfont{#1}}}

\begin{document}
    \Pfv
    
    \printglossary
\end{document}
```

This produces the following for me.

I want the glossary description i.e. `perfective` displayed as `Perfective` and the gloss i.e. `pfv` displayed in small caps. I tried renewing `\firstleipzigfont` as per the instructions of documentation, but it seems to make no change in the output. Is this a bug in glossaries?

[image: leipzig]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of problems with your code, and one probable-bug in `leipzig` (but I think the bug won't affect what you are trying to do.)

First, use either `\printglossaries` (to print all glossaries) or `\printglosses` (to print just your list of abbreviations). Both of those macros use a pre-defined  (`leipzig`-internal) glossary style which will probably look approximately like what you want. The code `\printglossary` uses the default glossary style that `glossaries` loads, which is `list`.

Second, the default display in `leipzig` is to put the abbreviation into smallcaps, so that will happen for you automatically if you use `\printglossaries` or `\printglosses`.

Third, if you want the description capitalized, put `\leipzigdesccapitalizetrue` somewhere in your preamble.

Fourth, renewing `\firstleipzigfont` is going to change how the font looks the first time you use it in the text itself (not in the glossary). But this doesn't seem to be working correctly. (See code below where I try to change the first usage to italics, but it does not change.) I'll have to look into it.

Still, it sounds like you just want to control how the glossary is displayed, right? Try the code below and let me know if that helps:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[block]{leipzig} % use [block] to get block style
\makeglossaries

\renewcommand{\firstleipzigfont}[1]{\textit{#1}}% <-- should change first usage in text to italics, but doesn't; actual bug
\leipzigdesccapitalizetrue 

\begin{document}
    First: {\Pfv}. % should be italics; isn't
    After first: {\Pfv}.
    
    \printglossaries 
    % or \printglosses, 
    % or  \printglossary[style=block], 
    % but not \printglossary by itself, unless you want to define your own style
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation. It worked for me. I'll follow your suggestion.